# "Currency Displayed As" does not update previous data in Google Analytics eCommerce Reports

Tags: google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

My store is in a different currency than USD. I noticed that Google Analytics reports are showing amounts in USD (values are converted to USD equivalent).

I've already updated "Currency Displayed As" to MXN (Mexican Pesos), but the values haven't changed. I wonder if previous data that came through before updating this setting won't be affected.

As you can see in the screenshot, $86.64 are USD, the original amount is $1,700 MXN
[image]

The data is actually provided in the original currency, I'm sure about that because the conversion that google applies to USD is accurate. $1,600 MXN = $86.64 USD

Can somebody explain this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the currency in the Google Analytics View settings, it will not affect the past data and will only apply to the future E-commerce data.